# PowerApps Attachments

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have a PowerApps which allows the team to attach files. The information entered in the App is linked to Sharepoint. Once I export all the data from Sharepoint, I am unable to see any link to the attachments. Is there a way to export a link for those attachments in excel?

Answer (score 0):

It is by design and we cannot export to excel with attachment column.

As a workaround, you can create a multiple-line column to save all links URL of the list attachments and create a flow as follows to get the links in the list and then use the Export to Excel option to get the links' URL in the Excel file.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Similar issue for your reference:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/export-sharepoint-list-with-attachments/c48efbe0-3b71-4869-8a59-d9ae2dff71cf